# Cannot use im.getcolors

Tags: python, image, colors, python-imaging-library

I was trying this code:

```
im = Image.open("myimage") 
colors = im.getcolors()
print colors
```

and it returns "None". So I tried this:

```
im = Image.open("myimage") 
size = im.size 
colors = im.getcolors(size[0]*size[1])
```

and when I "print colors" with this, Python basically crashes. I'm not using a huge image. How can I make it work?

My goal is to know from an image how many pixels are closer to black and how many px are closer to white. Maybe im.getcolors it's not the right solution?

Comment: you could use the fun .getpixels()

Comment: @AvinashBabu with .getpixels() i should analyse them one by one right?

Answer (score 4):

The image has to be in RGB mode in order to use `getcolors`. So try:

```
    im_rgb = im.convert('RGB')
    colors = im_rgb.getcolors()
    print colors
```

Answer (score 1):

```
im_rgb = im.convert('RGB')
colors = im_rgb.getcolors(maxcolors=1000000) #max colors to show
print(colors)
```