# im.getcolors() returns None

Tags: python, image-processing

I am using a simple code to compare an image to a desktop screenshot through the function getcolors() from PIL. When I open an image, it works:

```
im = Image.open('sprites\Bowser\BowserOriginal.png')
current_sprite = im.getcolors() 
print current_sprite
```

However, using both pyautogui.screenshot() and ImageGrab.grab() for the screenshot, my code returns none. I have tried using the RGB conversion as shown here: [Cannot use im.getcolors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27579899/cannot-use-im-getcolors).

Additionally, even when I save a screenshot to a .png, it STILL returns none.

```
i = pyautogui.screenshot('screenshot.png')
f = Image.open('screenshot.png')
im = f.convert('RGB')
search_image = im.getcolors()
print search_image
```

First time posting, help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 14):

Pretty old question but for those who sees this now:

**Image.getcolors()** takes as a parameter "maxcolors – Maximum number of colors." (from the docs [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.0.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getcolors)).

The maximum number of colors an image can have, equals to the number of pixels it contains.
For example, an image of 50*60px will have maximum 3,000 colors.

To translate it into code, try this:

```
# Open the image.
img = Image.open("test.jpg")
# Set the maxcolors number to the image's pixels number.
colors = img.getcolors(img.size[0]*img.size[1])
```

Answer (score 5):

If you'd check the docs, getcolors returns `None` if the number of colors in the image is greater than the default parameter, which is set to 256.