# Is there an efficient way to bin the main colors from an RGB image?

Tags: python, image-processing, colors, python-imaging-library, rgb

I am working on a project where, loosely put, I'd like to extract the top *n* colors from an image along with a measure of the relative popularity of each. I started out using PIL and the `getcolors()` method but quickly ran into the problem of converting the (frequency, color) tuples `getcolors()` returns back to RGB values—or even to colors in a PIL palette. That said, the upshot of PIL is that it maps the RGB values to a single dimension.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

filename ='test_img.png'

imgP = Image.open('/Users/JohnDoe/Documents' + filename).convert('P')

totalpix = imgP.size[0]*imgP.size[1]

# Get colors
colors = imgP.getcolors()
colors.sort(key=itemgetter(0))
colors.reverse()

colorfreq = np.zeros(len(colors))
colorindex = np.zeros_like(colorfreq)

# Determine the most common colors and their indices
for i, c in enumerate(colors):
    colorfreq[i] = c[0]
    colorindex[i] = c[1]

    if colorfreq.sum() > totalpix*0.95:
        colorfreq = np.delete(np.unique(colorfreq), 0)
        colorindex = np.delete(np.unique(colorindex), 0)
        print("Number of colors extracted: " + str(colorfreq.shape[0]))
        break
```

Having run into the above roadblock I thought I'd turn to matplotlib. However, while it's easy enough to get an array of RGB values, I'm not sure how to bin it appropriately. I looked into matplotlib colormaps and [colormap normalization](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-colors-colormapnorms-py) but this doesn't seem relevant for an image that's already in color. What comes to mind next is to create "bins" of RGB values and extract the main colors in that way. I don't know if that's possible, though, and in any case suspect there's a better method.

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np

filename ='test_img.png'

# Read image and remove the alpha values
img = mpimg.imread('/Users/JohnDoe/Documents/' + filename)
img = img[:, :, 0:3]
```

Thanks for your input!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot use im.getcolors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27579899/cannot-use-im-getcolors)

Comment: @quamrana: Not quite. As I understand it, `getcolors()` actually needs an image that is in 'P' mode (or '1' or 'L'), hence the `.convert('P')` in my code using PIL, above. See: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/PIL/Image.html#Image.getcolors.

Comment: And yet one of the answers suggests: `colors = im_rgb.getcolors()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I happen to have pillow 6.2.1 if that matters.

Also the documentation for `getcolors()` points out that if the actual number of colors in the image exceeds the `maxcolors` parameter, then `None` is returned.

So, my own experiment goes like this:

```
img = Image.open(filename)
im_rgb = img.convert('RGB')
colors = im_rgb.getcolors(maxcolors=200000)   # A suitably large number empirically determined 
print(len(colors))
colors = sorted(colors, key = lambda x:-x[0])
print(im_rgb)
print(colors[:12])
```

Output:

```
21407
<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=144x256 at 0x3E9DE90>
[(43, (36, 30, 14)), (42, (38, 29, 12)), (39, (35, 29, 13)), (37, (41, 33, 14)), (35, (42, 34, 15)), (32, (37, 28, 11)), (32, (2, 2, 2)), (32, (44, 36, 17)), (31, (37, 30, 12)), (30, (31, 25, 11)), (29, (43, 35, 16)), (28, (46, 35, 15))]
```

As you can see, the image happens to have 21407 different colours and I've printed out the top 12. Each color is a tuple, presumably in the form `(r, g, b)`

Comment: Thanks! This is very much what I was looking for. I suppose the trouble I was having came from not specifying the right number of colors when calling `getcolors()`, so that all that call was returning was `None`.

Comment: With the colors in hand, is there an efficient way to bin _these_? So that from, say, 21407 colors we can get, for example, 2000? Essentially, is there an efficient way to determine that, for example, (43, (36, 30, 14)) and (42, (38, 29, 12)) are within some range of each other and should be counted together, as something like (85, (40, 30, 10))?

Comment: It looks like maybe using `np.histogramdd()` with the first index of each pair serving as a weight might work?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I was able to figure out in the end, making using of `np.histogramdd()` and @quamrana's helpful answer.

Thanks for the help! (Still, any efficiency tips appreciated.)

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import log10, sqrt
from numpy.random import default_rng

im_rgb = Image.open(filename).convert('RGB')
colors = im_rgb.getcolors(maxcolors=200000)   # A suitably large number empirically determined

colors = sorted(colors, key = lambda x:-x[0])

threshold = 250
near_white = [c for c in colors if c[1][0] > threshold and c[1][1] > threshold and c[1][2] > threshold]
removed = 0
for c in near_white:
    colors.pop(colors.index(c))
    removed += 1

print(str(removed) + " colors near white removed.")

RGB = [[c[1][i]/255 for i in range(3)] for c in colors]
freq =[c[0] for c in colors]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

bins = 10
hist, binedges = np.histogramdd(np.array(RGB), bins=bins, weights=freq)

rg = default_rng(12345)
plot_width = 50
plot_height = plot_width
for x, _ in enumerate(binedges[0][0:-1]):
    for y, _ in enumerate(binedges[1][0:-1]):
        for z, _ in enumerate(binedges[2][0:-1]):
            rect_x = rg.random() * plot_width - plot_width / 2
            rect_y = rg.random() * plot_height - plot_height / 2
            rect_w = 100*log10(1+ sqrt(hist[x, y, z] / hist.sum()))
            rect_h = rect_w
            c = (binedges[0][x] + 0.5/bins, binedges[1][y] + 0.5/bins, binedges[2][z] +  0.5/bins)
            ax.add_patch(plt.Rectangle((rect_x, rect_y), rect_w, rect_h, color=c, alpha=1.))

ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.set_xlim(auto=True)
ax.set_ylim(auto=True)
ax.plot()
plt.show()
```